# Calling a js script from php doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to 'call' a function stored in my .js file from a .php page using this :

```
echo "<script>myFunction(arg1, arg2)</script>";
```

and it just doesn't go though. But it works when I use html instead :

```
<script>myFunction(arg1, arg2)</script>
```

I'll probably feel stupid when you'll provide me with the answer but I just don't get it.
Thanks!

EDIT: sorry, more details. The function pops an alert dialog, and I'm calling it **when the page just got loaded**

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: I'm a little confused...are you sure you're `echo`ing  inside `<?php` block?

Comment: Is the `myFunction` code included *before* you make the echo call? Also check your error console.

Comment: "and it just doesn't go though." Maybe explain what you mean by this, doesn't it load it, itsn't it displayed in the html source?

Comment: What is the definition for `MyFunction` ? Where is the `<script>` Tag in your HTML ?

Answer (score 2):

Understand that what you are doing is instructing the web server to output that line of JavaScript to the web page.  This will simply be sent to the user as it appears above.  Once the user's browser sees that line, it will execute the JavaScript on the client side (ie: in the user's browser).  The JavaScript won't and can't be executed on the server (in case you were implying that).

One thing to check is if you are calling that function *before* the actual function declaration (it won't work under those circumstances).  Browse to that web page and inspect the HTML source to see where that function appears on the page.  If it is before the function declaration, you will need to place it after.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be in a .js file

```
//dummy.js
function myFunciton(arg1, arg2)
{
   alert (arg1 + arg2);
}
```

in your PHP page

```
//dummy.php
<script src='dummy.js'></script>
<?php
    echo "<script>myFunction('arg1', 'arg2')</script>";
?>
```

Please note that your function should be initialized before calling it. And also if you are passing string to function enclose them in quotes

Comment: my function is in a .js file, and it's initialized before I call it. If I just remove the echo close my php block and use html, it works like it's supposed to

Comment: open the php page in browser which is not working, and check its source code. What is printed for echo line

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your js function is declared before or wrap the call into document.ready. Then your code will work.

Comment: I tried that already, not working either